# Is a positive operator symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra

A question just came up in my mind right now, is a positive operator symmetric? I'm trying to prove this using the properties of positive operators, but I'm stuck, I need a hand here.

Thanks

Comment: By positive you mean positive definite, right?

Comment: @detnvvp what's the definition of positive definite?

Comment: $(Tu,u)\geq 0$ for all $u$, where $u$ is the inner product of your space. What is your definition of positive?

Comment: the same as yours

Answer (score 2):

This drives me nuts. Every square matrix $A$ can be written as the sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew symmetric matrix.

So, $$ A = B + C; \; \; B^T = B; \; \; C^T = - C. $$
Recipe: $$ B = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T); \; \; C =   \frac{1}{2}(A - A^T). $$

We need to know that the transpose of a number, a one by one matrix, is itself.
Now, given a column vector $v,$ we find
$$  v^T C v  = (v^T C v)^T = v^T C^T v = - v^T C v. $$
So $$  v^T C v  = 0. $$

Then, $$ v^T A v = v^T B v + v^T C v = v^T B v.   $$

So, the quadratic form constructed from a (square) real matrix is defined entirely by the symmetric part. Positivity is determined by the symmetric part.

For reasons entirely beyond my understanding, people discuss positivity for matrices that may not be symmetric. There is no real need to do this.

AHHHHAAAAA!!!!  Horn and Johnson, *Matrix Analysis* (1985). This is pretty much the standard reference for matrices; check wikipedia. Page 397:

> ***Exercise.***  Show that if $A \in M_n $ is a real matrix and if $x^T A x$ is positive for all nonzero $x \in \mathbb R^n,$ then $A$
>   need not be symmetric, and hence it need not be positive definite.
>   *Hint:* Consider a real skew-symmetric matrix $A$ and compute $(x^TAx)^T.$ What is $x^T A x$ in this case? What about $x^\ast A x$ for
>   nonreal $x?$

Note that for any matrix $P,$ the symbol $P^\ast$ is the conjugate transpose of $P.$

Comment: To Dr. Will Jagy:  Is *that* what drives you nuts, Dr. Jagy?  Me, I have other drivers toward nuttiness . . . *all* mathematical, of course!  Cheers! ;-) ;-) ;-)!!!

Comment: @RobertLewis, just one item of many. Out of existence and uniqueness, this establishes only existence of things that drive me nuts.

Comment: To Will Jagy:  Hear, hear!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily true, consider the matrix $\left(\begin{array}{c c} 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 2\end{array}\right)$. Then, $$(x,y)\left(\begin{array}{c c} 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 2\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} x \\ y\end{array}\right)=2x^2+2xy+2y^2=(x+y)^2+x^2+y^2,$$ so the operator $Tx=Ax$ is positive definite. However, $A$ is not symmetric.

Comment: but every positive operator is self-adjoint which is the same as symmetric. Am I wrong?

Comment: You could impose symmetry as part of your definition of positive definite operators (and this is what is usually done). However, as this example shows, the condition $(Tu,u)\geq 0$ for all $u$ does not imply in general that $T$ is symmetric.

Comment: Self-adjoint is typically used in the complex situation, the positivity should then also be taken to be with complex vectors. These are indeed equivalent: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/561636