# Show that a positive operator on a complex Hilbert space is self-adjoint

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $(\mathcal{H}, (\cdot, \cdot))$ be a complex Hilbert space, and $A :  \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ a positive, bounded operator ($A$ being positive means $(Ax,x) \ge 0$ for all $x \in \mathcal{H}$).

Prove that $A$ is self-adjoint. That is, prove that $(Ax,y) = (x, Ay)$ for all $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$.

Here's what I have so far. Because $A$ is positive we have $\mathbb{R} \ni (Ax,x) = \overline{(x,Ax)} = (x,Ax)$, all $x \in \mathcal{H}$.

Next, I have seen some hints that tell me to apply the polarization identity:

$$(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}((\lVert x+y \rVert^2 + \lVert x-y \rVert^2) - i(\lVert x + iy \rVert^2 - \lVert x - iy \rVert^2)),$$

where of course the norm is defined by $\lVert \cdot \rVert^2 = (\cdot, \cdot)$. So my guess is that I need to start with the expressions:

$$(Ax,y) = \frac{1}{4}((\lVert Ax+y \rVert^2 + \lVert Ax-y \rVert^2) - i(\lVert Ax + iy \rVert^2 - \lVert Ax - iy \rVert^2)),$$

$$(x,Ay) = \frac{1}{4}((\lVert x+Ay \rVert^2 + \lVert x-Ay \rVert^2) - i(\lVert x + iAy \rVert^2 - \lVert x - iAy \rVert^2)),$$

and somehow show they are equal. But here is where I have gotten stuck.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should apply the polarization identity in the form

$$4(Ax,y) = (A(x+y),x+y) - (A(x-y),x-y) -i(A(x+iy),x+iy) + i(A(x-iy),x-iy).$$

Since you already know $(Az,z) = (z,Az)$ for all $z \in \mathcal{H}$, it is not difficult to deduce $A^\ast = A$ from that.

Comment: Consider the operator on 2D Hilbert space given by the matrix $A = \left[\begin{matrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{matrix}\right]$.  Isn't this positive, but not self-adjoint?  What am I missing?

Comment: $(Ax,x) = 2(1+i)$ isn't real for $x = (1,i)$.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that 10 seconds before your post!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Should we have a minus sign in front of the term $(A(x-y), x-y)$?

Comment: @jtms88 Yes, of course. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: Can you give a hint of how this form of the polarization identity is derived?  This is not the usual form that I have seen, which is just $(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}\sum_{k=0}^3 i^k \| x + i^k y\|$

Comment: @DanielFischer I would appreciate the above too

Comment: @Squirtle The polarization identity holds for any sesquilinear form $S$; in the form $$4\cdot S(x,y) = \sum_{k = 0}^3 i^k\cdot S(x+i^ky, x+i^ky)$$ if "sesquilinear" means linear in the first argument and antilinear in the second, and in the form $$4\cdot S(x,y) = \sum_{k = 0}^3 (-i)^kS(x+i^ky,x+i^ky)$$ if antilinear in the first and linear in the second (which for some unfathomable reason I seem to have assumed in the answer - perhaps not so unfathomable, it matches the signs of $i\lVert x\pm iy\rVert$ in the question). To see that, just expand the sum using sesquilinearity. Correspondingly,

Comment: the real version of the polarisation identity does not only hold for norms given by an inner product, it holds for all _symmetric_ bilinear forms (and that not only over $\mathbb{R}$ but over any field whose characteristic is different from $2$). Coming back to the topic, the map $(x,y) \mapsto S(Ax,y)$ is a sesquilinear form for every linear $A \colon \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ and every sesquilinear form $S\colon\mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{H}\to\mathbb{C}$, in particular if $S$ is an inner product. (@JoãoBravo, too)

Answer (score 7):

Another solution is this one:

$T$ is self-adjoint iff $\langle Tx,x\rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $x\in \mathcal{H}$.

Let $x\in \mathcal{H}$. Then $0=\langle Tx,x \rangle-\langle T^{*}x,x \rangle = \langle Tx,x \rangle-\overline{\langle Tx,x \rangle}=2i\operatorname{Im}\langle Tx,x\rangle  \iff \langle Tx,x \rangle \in \mathbb{R}$. Thus $T=T^{*} \iff \langle Tx,x\rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ for every $x\in \mathcal{H}$.

Because $T$ is positive we have that $\langle Tx,x \rangle \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @jtms88 ,check my proof please.thank you

Comment: It isn't complete since you cannot conclude that $T=T^*$ from $\langle Tx,x\rangle=\langle T^*x,x\rangle$. You still need to use an argument similar to the one given by Daniel Fischer to deduce it.

Answer (score -1):

We can write
A = R + iI where R, I are Hermitian (self adj.)

As is standard for self adjoint operators,
⟨x,Ry⟩, ⟨x, Iy⟩, ⟨Rx, y⟩, ⟨Ix, y⟩ are real.

Further,
⟨x,Ax⟩ = ⟨x,Rx⟩ + i ⟨x, Ix⟩ all real, by hypothesis.

So,
⟨x, Ix⟩ = 0 ∀ x ∈ V. By conjugacy ⟨Ix, x⟩ = 0 (2.6)

Now
⟨I(x + y), x + y⟩ = ⟨I(x), x⟩ + ⟨I(x), y⟩ + ⟨I(y), x⟩ + ⟨I(y), y⟩ ⇒

0 = ⟨I(x), y⟩ + ⟨I(y), x⟩ = ⟨I(x), y⟩ + ⟨y, Ix⟩ all real.

So,
0 = ⟨I(x), y⟩ + ⟨Ix, y⟩ by conjugacy.

So,
0 = 2 ⟨I(x), y⟩ . Therefore, ⟨I(x), y⟩ = 0 ∀x, y ∈ V.
From this it follows Ix = 0 ∀x.
That means A = R is hermitian.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Okay! I edited. This is a complete proof.