# Square-root for nonnegative (and not necessarily self-adjoint) operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $H$ be a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space and $A$ be a bounded linear operator on $H$. If $A$ is nonnegative and self-adjoint, then there is a unique nonnegative and self-adjoint bounded linear operator $B$ on $H$ with $B^2=A$. This can be proved by an elementary version of the spectral theorem.

Now, suppose that $A$ is only nonnegative (and not necessarily self-adjoint). I've read that we can still find a unique nonnegative bounded linear operator $B$ on $H$ with $B^2=A$. How can we prove this statement?

My knowledge in operator theory is rather limited. So, I hope we can provide an elementary proof.

Comment: What does nonnegative mean for an operator which isn't self-adjoint?

Comment: @Qiaochu: I can't speak for the OP, but I guess it is supposed to mean $\langle Ax, x\rangle \geq 0$ for all $x $.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Is $A$ at least [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator)? If so, then there is the [continuous functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus) available that does what you want.

Comment: @0xbadf00d: Alternatively, consider a branch of the complex square root (it will be holomorphic on its domain of definition): if $A$ is not normal but its spectrum is contained in the domain of this complex square root, then you may use the [holomorphic functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561636/show-that-a-positive-operator-on-a-complex-hilbert-space-is-self-adjoint

Comment: @san: This is a good remark, but the links considers **complex** Hilbert spaces. In contrast, the OP considers **real** Hilbert spaces. In those spaces, it is not true that every nonnegative (in the sense of $\langle Ax, x\rangle \geq 0$ operator is self-adjoint. A counterexample is any operator with $A^\ast = -A$, i.e., any skew-symmetric matrix in the finite dimensional case.

Comment: @AlexM.: Interesting idea! Directly from the definition and from the assumption, we get that every **real** eigenvalue of $A$ needs to be $\geq 0$. Hence, if we can somehow work around the case when $0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then we can apply the holomorphic functional calculus to get **some** square root (since there is a holomorphic square root on $\Bbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0]$ IIRC). It is not clear to me, however, if this square root is nonnegative (in the sense of the question at hand), and unique.

Comment: @PhoemueX: The problem is that those two functional calculi that I mention concern *complex* Hilbert spaces, while the OP assumes (quite weirdly) his space to be real, a fact that I've missed until reading your comment above.