# If $M\geq 0$, why $M$ is invertible if and only if $\left< Mv, v \right> = 0$ implies that $v = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $\mathcal{B}(F)$ the algebra of all bounded linear operators on a complex finite dimensional Hilbert space $F$. Let $M\in \mathcal{B}(F)^+$ (i.e. $\langle Mx\;, \;x\rangle\geq 0$ for all $x\in F$.

I want to show that $M$ is invertible if and only if $\left< Mv, v \right> = 0$ implies that $v = 0$.

If $F$ is real finite dimensional Hilbert space. Is the above equivalence remains true?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A positive-semidefinite operator $M$ is [necessarily self-adjoint](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/561636/144766).

Since $F$ is finite-dimensional, there exists an orthonormal basis $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ for $F$ of eigenvectors for $M$. Assume the respective eigenvalues are $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$. Since $M$ is self-adjoint, the eigenvalues are real, and since $M$ is positive-semidefinite, we have $\lambda_i \ge 0$.

For $v \in F$ we have:

\begin{align}
\langle Mv, v\rangle &= \left\langle M\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \langle v, e_i\rangle e_i\right), \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v, e_i\rangle e_i\right\rangle\\
&= \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v, e_i\rangle Me_i, \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v, e_i\rangle e_i\right\rangle\\
&= \left\langle \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v, e_i\rangle \lambda_ie_i, \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v, e_i\rangle e_i\right\rangle\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n \left|\langle v, e_i\rangle\right|^2\lambda_i
\end{align}

Assume $\langle Mx, x\rangle = 0 \implies x = 0$. To show that $M$ is invertible, it suffices to show $\operatorname{Ker}\, M = \{0\}$. Let $Mx = 0$. We have

$$\langle Mx, x\rangle = \langle 0, x\rangle = 0 \implies x = 0$$

Hence, $\operatorname{Ker}\, M = \{0\}$ so $M$ is invertible.

Now, assume that $M$ is invertible. This means that $\lambda_i > 0$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

For every $x \ne 0$ we have that $\left|\langle x, e_i\rangle\right| \ne 0$ for some $i$. Therefore:

$$\langle Mx, x \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \left|\langle v, e_i\rangle\right|^2\lambda_i \ge \left|\langle x, e_i\rangle\right|^2\lambda_i > 0$$

We conclude that $\langle Mx, x\rangle = 0 \implies x = 0$.

Comment: If F is real finite dimensional Hilbert space. Is the above equivalence remains true?thank  you.

Comment: @Thierry If $F$ is real then it's not true in general. The implication $M$ positive implies $M$ invertible still holds, but $M$ invertible does not imply $M$ positive. Consider an operator given by the skew-symmetric matrix $A^* = -A$, such as $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$. We have that $A$ is invertible, but $\langle Ax, x \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in F$ so $A$ is positive semidefinite, but not positive.

Comment: Dear, I think there exists a small mistake: I think you should write ''**orthonormal** basis $\{e_1, \ldots, e_n\}$ for $F$ (not $b_k$) of eigenvectors for $M$. Assume the **associated** eigenvalues are $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$.''  Do you agree with me? Thanks

Comment: @Schüler Yes, fixed now, thanks.

Comment: Please I have a question. To be precise:  $M$ is invertible if and only if if there exists $v$ such that $\left< Mv, v \right> = 0$ then $v = 0$. Or the place of there exists we have for all? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Schüler $M$ is invertible if and only if for all $v \in F$ we have $\langle Mv,v\rangle = 0 \implies v = 0$. The statement "there exists $v \in F$ such that $\langle Mv,v\rangle = 0 \implies v = 0$" is always true, namely plug in $v = 0$.

Comment: @Schüler Much shorter proof than mine above: since $M \ge 0$ it has a square root $M^{1/2} \ge 0$. The condition $\langle Mv,v\rangle = 0 \implies v = 0$ is equivalent to $$\|M^{1/2}v\|^2 = \langle M^{1/2}v, M^{1/2}v\rangle = 0 \implies v= 0$$ which is equivalent to $\ker M^{1/2} = \{0\}$ which is equivalent to $M^{1/2}$ being invertible. Now, $M^{1/2}$ is invertible if and only if $M$ is invertible, with the inverse being $(M^{1/2})^{-1} = (M^{-1})^{1/2}$.

Comment: And the statement seems false in infinite dimensions: consider $M = \operatorname{diag} \left(\frac1n\right)_n \in \mathbb{B}(\ell^2)$. Then $M \ge 0$ and $\langle Mv,v\rangle = 0 \implies v = 0$ but $M$ is not invertible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great explanation.