# About operators and spectrum

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

Cordial greetings.

My first concern in this post is the following: we know that for real numbers $S,T$ is true $$\left(S\geq T\quad\mbox{and}\quad T\geq S\right)\Longrightarrow S=T.$$

1. Now, *if $S,T$ are bounded linear operators defined in a Hilbert space $H$, is this still true?*
2. While reading about operator theory in a book, they stated that if T is positive, then this operator is self-adjoint. I suppose this is trivial, but I have not been able to find the justification.

Comment: For your first question, the answer is yes if the Hilbert space is complex. Your hypothesis implies that for every $x \in H, \langle Tx, x \rangle = \langle Sx, x \rangle$. Now use the polarization identity to deduce that for all $x, y \in H, \langle Tx, y \rangle = \langle Sx, y \rangle$, from which it follows that $T = S$. Your second question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561636/show-that-a-positive-operator-on-a-complex-hilbert-space-is-self-adjoint.

Comment: For both parts yuo have assume that the scalar field is $\mathbb C$. They are false when the scalar field is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @C_M If $T$ is rotation by $90^{0}$ in $\mathbb R^{2}$ then $\langle Tx, x \rangle =0$ for all $x$ but $T \neq 0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy You are right, of course. I forgot to state that we need $H$ to be a complex vector space. I edited my first comment.