# Inequality for $\langle T^2x, x\rangle$ if $T$ is positive operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators

Let $T \in \mathcal{L} (\mathcal{H})$ is positive operator (i.e. $\langle T x, x \rangle \ge 0$). Prove that $$\langle T^2 x, x \rangle \le \langle Tx, x \rangle^{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \ldots + \frac{1}{2^k}} \langle T^{2^k +1} x, x \rangle^\frac{1}{2^k}.$$
So I tried to use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality that is
$$| \langle Tx, y \rangle| \le \langle Tx, x \rangle^\frac{1}{2} \langle Ty, y \rangle^\frac{1}{2}$$
and put $y = Tx$ which implies
$$| \langle Tx, Tx \rangle| \le \langle Tx, x \rangle^\frac{1}{2} \langle T^2x, Tx \rangle^\frac{1}{2}.$$

Is it true that any positive operator in Hilbert space is self-adjoint and I can use that $T^* = T$ to get
$$| \langle T^2x, x \rangle| \le \langle Tx, x \rangle^\frac{1}{2} \langle T^3x, x \rangle^\frac{1}{2},$$
which proves the base of induction?

Comment: On a complex Hilbert space, a positive operator *in your sense* is self-adjoint, but it is not the case on a real Hilbert space, though I think the usual definition of "positive operator" includes self-adjointness.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561636/show-that-a-positive-operator-on-a-complex-hilbert-space-is-self-adjoint

Answer (score 0):

It is often assumed (and practical) to assume that $T$ is selfadjoint when you say it's "positive". When $H$ is a complex Hilbert space, positivity in the sense of

> $$\tag 1
> \langle Tx,x\rangle\geq0\qquad\qquad\text{ for all } x.
> $$

implies $T^*=T$. In the real case it doesn't, but let us look at what the problem is.

The problem is, for instance, that if you only assume that $(1)$ holds, then $\langle Tx,x\rangle\geq0$ does **not** imply that $\langle T^2x,x\rangle\geq0$. Example:
$$
\bigg\langle\begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\0&1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a\\b\end{bmatrix} ,\begin{bmatrix} a\\b\end{bmatrix} \bigg\rangle\geq0
$$
for all $a,b$, while
$$
\bigg\langle\begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\0&1 \end{bmatrix}^2 \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix} ,\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix} \bigg\rangle
=\bigg\langle\begin{bmatrix}1&-4\\0&1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix} ,\begin{bmatrix} 1\\1\end{bmatrix} \bigg\rangle
=-2<0.
$$