# Positive operator is symmetric?

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

If I understand correctly then for an operator $\mathcal{A}$ defined on a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$, $\langle \mathcal{A}x,x\rangle\geq 0$ does not necessarily imply that $\mathcal{A}$ is Hermitian: $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{A}^\ast$. See for instance [Is a positive operator symmetric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545149/is-a-positive-operator-symmetric)

However I was shown the following proof of the supposedly erroneous statement and was wondering if there is something wrong in it for I can't find it myself?

Lemma 1: $\langle Tx,x\rangle = 0$ for every $x\in \mathcal{H}$ implies that $T \equiv 0$.

Proof: We show that $\langle Tx,y\rangle = 0$ for every pair $x,y\in \mathcal{H}.$ Indeed

\begin{align*}
0 = \langle T(x+y),x+y\rangle - \langle T(x-y),x-y\rangle & = 2\langle Tx,y\rangle+2\langle Ty,x\rangle.
\end{align*}
This implies that
$$\langle Tx,y\rangle = -\langle Ty,x\rangle.$$

Exchanging $x$ with $ix$ yields

$$0 = i\langle Tx,y\rangle -i\langle Ty,x\rangle$$
why
$$\langle Tx,y\rangle = \langle Ty,x\rangle$$
all in all we find that $\langle Tx,y\rangle = \pm \langle Ty,x\rangle$ which implies that both are $0$.

Proof that $\langle \mathcal{A}x,x\rangle\geq 0$ implies that $\mathcal{A}^\ast = \mathcal{A}$:

We have that

$$\mathbb{R}\ni\langle \mathcal{A}x,x\rangle = \langle x,\mathcal{A}^\ast x\rangle = \overline{\langle \mathcal{A}^\ast x,x\rangle } = \langle \mathcal{A}^\ast x, x\rangle\Rightarrow \langle (\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{A}^\ast)x,x\rangle = 0$$
for every $x$ thus by the lemma $\mathcal{A}-\mathcal{A}^\ast\equiv 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case complex scalars $\langle Tx,x \rangle=0$ for all $x$ implies $T=0$ and  $\langle Tx,x \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x$ implies $T=T^{*}$ (as you have shown). This is not true for real scalars.  Rotation by $90$ degrees on $\mathbb R^{2}$ is a counter example.

Comment: Ok very interesting thank you! I see now that the counterexample in the linked post assumes that we only allow real scalars.