# Positive operator on a complex Hilbert space is symmetric?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I've read somewhere that a positive operator on a complex Hilbert space is necessarily symmetric. I don't know how to prove this claim.

What I call a positive operator on $\mathfrak{h}$ is an operator $A : \mathcal{D}(A) \to \mathfrak{h}$ such that $\langle Ax, x \rangle \geq 0$ for every $x \in \mathcal{D}(A)$. Remember that here I'm only talking about symmetric-ness, not self-adjoint-ness !

Any help greatly appreciated !

Comment: What is your definition of a symmetric operator? I used to think it is the same thing as self-adjoint.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this question has been answered here before. The trick is to evaluate the expressions $\langle A(x\pm iy),x\pm iy\rangle$ to see that the real and imaginary part of $\langle Ax,y\rangle-\langle x,Ay\rangle$ are zero.

Comment: Thanks @MaoWao for the answer, but could you be a little bit more explicit ? I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positive operator is symmetric?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060482/positive-operator-is-symmetric)

Comment: I'm working with a complete general operator $A$, that is not defined on the all $\mathfrak{h}$. First and foremost, I cannot use $A^*$ as it might not exist...

Comment: I've managed to prove that the Real part was zero, but I don't see what's the trick for the imaginery part...

Comment: Fair point. I retracted my close vote and wrote an answer instead (my comment above might have been misleading, you need to also consider expressions of the form $\langle A(x+y),x+y\rangle$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$
\mathbb{R}\ni\langle A(x+y),x+y\rangle=\langle Ax,x\rangle+\langle Ay,y\rangle+\langle Ax,y\rangle+\langle Ay,x\rangle.
$$
Thus $\langle Ax,y\rangle+\langle Ay,x\rangle=\langle x,Ay\rangle+\langle y,Ax\rangle$.

Moreover,
$$
\mathbb{R}\ni \langle A(x-iy),x-iy\rangle=\langle Ax,x\rangle+\langle Ay,y\rangle+i\langle Ax,y\rangle-i\langle Ay,x\rangle,
$$
which implies $\langle Ax,y\rangle-\langle Ay,x\rangle=\langle x,Ay\rangle-\langle y,Ax\rangle$.

If you add up these to equalities, you arrive at $\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,Ay\rangle$.

Comment: Hi! I am wondering how you got the equation in third line. Also, in the fifth line, shouldn't the sign on $\left<Ay,y \right>$ be negative? Thanks,

Comment: In the third line, the RHS is the complex conjugate of the LHS. But the LHS is real according to the second line ($\langle Ax,x\rangle$ and $\langle Ay,y\rangle$ are real by assumption). The sign in the fifth line is correct - remember that the inner product is conjugate linear in one argument, so that $\langle \lambda u,\lambda v\rangle=|\lambda|^2\langle u,v\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am still confused with the third line part. I know $$\left<x,y  \right>=\overline{\left< y,x  \right>}$$ so we have $$\overline{\left<Ax,y \right>}=\left<y,Ax \right>=\left< A^*y,x \right>$$ which is different

Comment: We have $\overline{\langle Ax,y\rangle}=\langle y,Ax\rangle$ and $\overline{\langle Ay,x\rangle}=\langle x,Ay\rangle$. The summands on the RHS are in the reverse order of the LHS, maybe that is waht confused you.

Comment: AhAh.. Thank you! (+1)

Comment: The RHS of the equation in the sixth line should be $\langle x,A(y)\rangle-\langle y,A(x)\rangle$.

Comment: @Stephen You are right. Corrected.